# Python RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
K_1 = [(-1, 196), (1, 197), (-1, 210), (Fraction(1, 15), 14)]

r_1, r_2 = 0, 0
for i in range(1, len(K_1)):
    if K_1[i][0] < 0:
        r_1 += Fraction(K_1[i][0], -1 * K_1[i][1])  #alpha in alpha
    else:
        r_2 += Fraction(K_1[i][0], -1 *  K_1[i][1]) #beta in alpha
```

I receive the following warning messages:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  return Fraction(a.numerator * db + b.numerator * da,

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  da * db)
```

Comment: Ask the loop to print `i` so as to see when the overflows occur

Comment: What version of python are you running? under 3.6 I don't get this warning.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh, could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @sgillen I'm running 3.6.5

Comment: @will_f, it is strange, since it prints all values for i

Comment: @jonan on 3.6.8 I don't see the error. Also what are the values for r_1 and r_2 when you run this code on your machine?

Comment: From the `Fraction` doc page: "[t]he first version requires that numerator and denominator are instances of `numbers.Rational`".  It doesn't say anything about casting an `int` as a `numbers.Rational` default behavior, so maybe that's the problem?  The solution would be to use `Fraction(1/15)` in that case